# sequelize.js belongsToMany on non-primary key

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I made API server with Node.js.

Also I use sequelize(version 4) for communicate with MySQL.

My database structure is simple follow system.

[model.js]

```
export const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    no: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    userid: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    userpw: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true
})
```

I heard that if there is no option about `targetKey`, Primary key will be refered automatically.

But if `targetKey` exist, refer that column.

So I defined association like this.

```
User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'follower', through: 'follow', foreignKey: 'follower_id', targetKey: 'userid'});
User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'following', through: 'follow', foreignKey: 'following_id', targetKey: 'userid'});
```

I want to refer User's `userid`. But after I run it, it still refer `no(PK)`.

Executed query in console is here.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `follow` (`created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `follower_id` INTEGER , `following_id` INTEGER , PRIMARY KEY (`follower_id`, `following_id`), FOREIGN KEY (`follower_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`no`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`following_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`no`) ONDELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Why still refer user's no column?

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`targetKey` is used with `belongsTo()`
You are using `belongsToMany()`, so according to [sequelize doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html), you should use `otherKey` instead of `targetKey` :

```
User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'follower', through: 'follow', foreignKey: 'follower_id', otherKey: 'userid'});
User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'following', through: 'follow', foreignKey: 'following_id', otherKey: 'userid'});
```

Answer (score 2):

As of [5.15.0](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/releases/tag/v5.15.0), support has been added for `sourceKey` and `targetKey` for many-to-many relationships. [This page](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#many-to-many-relationships) in the docs provides examples for this use case (at the bottom of the page).

Check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62705109/2057069) for more details.